# Can we call Google AdExchange Seller API using CURL?

Tags: google-dfp, adexchange

How do we call ad exchange seller api using curl.
We needs to create a script which will pull data dynamically and insert it to  database. Please help me I have tried below php script and working but to run script we need to click connect link.
Regards,
Mukesh

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @Mukesh have you figured this out? I am currently also wishing to do this